# Tensorflow: Object Detection using a Classification Checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

**System information**

- **What is the top-level directory of the model you are using:** object_detection/ssd_inception_v2 together with slim/InceptionV2
- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow):** No
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):** Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):** binary
- **TensorFlow version (use command below):** 1.2.1
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source):** no
- **CUDA/cuDNN version:** cuda 8.0
- **GPU model and memory:** Quadro M6000 24GB
- **Exact command to reproduce:**

I trained an inceptionV2 (from slim) on a (traffic sign) classification dataset. I then wanted to use the resulting checkpoint as a basis for the object detection API. If I understand correctly, it should be possible to just use and adapted version of the /object_detection/samples/configs/ ssd_inception_v2_pets.config config file. However when I run the object detection

*python object_detection/train.py --logtostderr   --pipeline_config_path=/home/tobi/tensorflow/trafficsigns/models/model/ssd_inception_v2_trafficsigns.config –train_dir=/home/tobi/tensorflow/trafficsigns/models/model/train*

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 198, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/tobi/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 194, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "/home/tobi/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/object_detection/trainer.py", line 191, in train
    clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, model_fn, [input_queue])
  File "/home/tobi/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 193, in create_clones
    outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tobi/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/object_detection/trainer.py", line 132, in _create_losses
    losses_dict = detection_model.loss(prediction_dict)
  File "/home/tobi/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 431, in loss
    location_losses, cls_losses, prediction_dict, match_list)
  File "/home/tobi/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py", line 551, in _apply_hard_mining
    [0, 0, 1], class_pred_shape), class_pred_shape)
  File "/home/tobi/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 547, in slice
    return gen_array_ops._slice(input_, begin, size, name=name)
  File "/home/tobi/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2896, in _slice
    name=name)
  File "/home/tobi/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 499, in apply_op
    repr(values), type(values).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int32 passed to parameter 'size' of op 'Slice', got [-1, None, 43] of type 'list' instead.
```

It seems to me the problem is that the anchor boxes are not initialized resulting in the ‘None’ value which lets the tf.Slice operation crash.

The config file I used

```
 # SSD with Inception v2 configured for Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset.
    # Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
    # well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
    # eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
    # should be configured.

    model {
      ssd {
        num_classes: 43
        box_coder {
          faster_rcnn_box_coder {
            y_scale: 10.0
            x_scale: 10.0
            height_scale: 5.0
            width_scale: 5.0
          }
        }
        matcher {
          argmax_matcher {
            matched_threshold: 0.5
            unmatched_threshold: 0.5
            ignore_thresholds: false
            negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
            force_match_for_each_row: true
          }
        }
        similarity_calculator {
          iou_similarity {
          }
        }
        anchor_generator {
          ssd_anchor_generator {
            num_layers: 6
            min_scale: 0.2
            max_scale: 0.95
            aspect_ratios: 1.0
            aspect_ratios: 2.0
            aspect_ratios: 0.5
            aspect_ratios: 3.0
            aspect_ratios: 0.3333
            reduce_boxes_in_lowest_layer: true
          }
        }
        image_resizer {
           keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
            min_dimension: 400
            max_dimension: 690
          }
        }
        box_predictor {
          convolutional_box_predictor {
            min_depth: 0
            max_depth: 0
            num_layers_before_predictor: 0
            use_dropout: false
            dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
            kernel_size: 3
            box_code_size: 4
            apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
            conv_hyperparams {
              activation: RELU_6,
              regularizer {
                l2_regularizer {
                  weight: 0.00004
                }
              }
              initializer {
                truncated_normal_initializer {
                  stddev: 0.03
                  mean: 0.0
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        feature_extractor {
          type: 'ssd_inception_v2'
          min_depth: 16
          depth_multiplier: 1.0
          conv_hyperparams {
            activation: RELU_6,
            regularizer {
              l2_regularizer {
                weight: 0.00004
              }
            }
            initializer {
              truncated_normal_initializer {
                stddev: 0.03
                mean: 0.0
              }
            }
            batch_norm {
              train: true,
              scale: true,
              center: true,
              decay: 0.9997,
              epsilon: 0.001,
            }
          }
        }
        loss {
          classification_loss {
            weighted_sigmoid {
              anchorwise_output: true
            }
          }
          localization_loss {
            weighted_smooth_l1 {
              anchorwise_output: true
            }
          }
          hard_example_miner {
            num_hard_examples: 3000
            iou_threshold: 0.99
            loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
            max_negatives_per_positive: 3
            min_negatives_per_image: 0
          }
          classification_weight: 1.0
          localization_weight: 1.0
        }
        normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
        post_processing {
          batch_non_max_suppression {
            score_threshold: 1e-8
            iou_threshold: 0.6
            max_detections_per_class: 100
            max_total_detections: 100
          }
          score_converter: SIGMOID
        }
      }
    }

    train_config: {
      batch_size: 24
      optimizer {
        rms_prop_optimizer: {
          learning_rate: {
            exponential_decay_learning_rate {
              initial_learning_rate: 0.004
              decay_steps: 800720
              decay_factor: 0.95
            }
          }
          momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
          decay: 0.9
          epsilon: 1.0
        }
      }
      fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/tobi/tensorflow/trafficsigns/models/pretrained/inception_v2_GTS/model.ckpt"
      from_detection_checkpoint: false
      # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
      # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
      # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
      # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
      #num_steps: 200000
      data_augmentation_options {
        random_horizontal_flip {
        }
      }
      data_augmentation_options {
        ssd_random_crop {
        }
      }
    }

    train_input_reader: {
      tf_record_input_reader {
        input_path: "/home/tobi/tensorflow/trafficsigns/data/train.record"
      }
      label_map_path: "/home/tobi/tensorflow/trafficsigns/data/ts_label_map.pbtxt"
    }

    eval_config: {
      num_examples: 2000
      num_visualizations: 25
      # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
      # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
      max_evals: 10
    }

    eval_input_reader: {
      tf_record_input_reader {
        input_path: "/home/tobi/tensorflow/trafficsigns/data/test.record"
      }
      label_map_path: "/home/tobi/tensorflow/trafficsigns/data/ts_label_map.pbtxt"
      shuffle: false
      num_readers: 1
    }
```

Any ideas what went wrong?
Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

After changing the *keep_aspect_ratio_resizer* to the *fixed_shape_resizer* in the config file as suggested (thx again) the training process started. I somehow get twice the logging messages which does not further bother me. What concerns me are the following warnings that indicate that the checkpoint does not contain expected variables. The training works anyway, I have not checked the results yet but I am not sure if I should ignore these.

```
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Conv2d_2b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Conv2d_2c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3b/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3b/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3b/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3b/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3c/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3c/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3c/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_3c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4a/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4a/Branch_0/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4a/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4a/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4a/Branch_1/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4b/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4b/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4b/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4b/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4c/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4c/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4c/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4d/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4d/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4d/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4d/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4d/Branch_2/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4d/Branch_2/Conv2d_0c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4d/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4e/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4e/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4e/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4e/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4e/Branch_2/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4e/Branch_2/Conv2d_0c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_4e/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5a/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5a/Branch_0/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5a/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5a/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5a/Branch_1/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5b/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5b/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5b/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5b/Branch_2/Conv2d_0c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5b/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_0/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0b_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_2/Conv2d_0c_3x3/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/weights] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_3_1x1_128/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_3_1x1_128/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_3_1x1_128/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_3_1x1_128/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_3_1x1_128/weights] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_4_1x1_128/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_4_1x1_128/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_4_1x1_128/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_4_1x1_128/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_4_1x1_128/weights] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_64/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_64/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_64/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_64/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_64/weights] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/weights] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256/weights] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_4_3x3_s2_256/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_4_3x3_s2_256/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_4_3x3_s2_256/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_4_3x3_s2_256/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_4_3x3_s2_256/weights] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/BatchNorm/gamma] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/BatchNorm/moving_mean] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/BatchNorm/moving_variance] not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/weights] not available in checkpoint
```

Comment: Can you post your config file too?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this issue, I added the config file

Comment: And can you say how your classification checkpoint was trained?  Was it using the slim inception v2 implementation?

Comment: Yes, I used the pretrained inception v2 checkpoint from slim as a basis for training on my dataset.

Comment: So I replaced 'self.anchors.num_boxes_static()' in the line class_pred_shape = [-1, self.anchors.num_boxes_static(), self.num_classes] in ssd_meta_arch.py by a magic number just to see if thats the problem. And I came a little further. I end up getting lot of warnings of the form WARNING:root:Variable [InceptionV2/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint and then errors of the form InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,690,356,3] vs. shape[1] = [1,400,680,3]. I can provide the whole error if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least one problem with the above config --- which is that the keep_aspect_ratio_resizer is incompatible with batch sizes greater than 1.  (I know this is not documented anywhere yet).  The problem is that after resizing each image, because the aspect ratios are preserved, all the images have a different shape and we then aren't able to stack them into a batch.

I recommend using a fixed shape like 300x300.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks for the hint, i will try your suggestion tomorrow and provide feedback asap.

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion did the job. I am now only left with the warnings about missing variables above and not sure if I need to change something. Would be great if you could clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file set the `fine_tune_checkpoint_type` in the train config to `"classification"` and `scale` and `center` in the batch norm to `false` like this:

```
train_config {
    fine_tune_checkpoint: "model.ckpt",
    fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "classification"
    from_detection_checkpoint: false
}


batch_norm {
    train: true,
    scale: false,
    center: false,
    decay: 0.9997,
    epsilon: 0.001,
}
```